# NODE-RED IBM WATSON : I am not able to create connection between the NODE-RED stater kit and speech to text service

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text, node-red

1. I have created NODE-RED stater kit which was created under an region,organisation , space .
2. Speech to text service was created under an resource group(default).
3. I opened NODE-RED stater kit from dashboard,clicked on connection->create connection.
4. It's showing no service available (although i created speech to text service earlier)

How do i bind/create connection between NODE-RED and speech to text service?

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple option here:

1) manually configure the speech-to-text node by unchecking the "Use Default Service Endpoint" box. Then select the service in ibm cloud and and use the information from there to fill up the fields in the node:

```
- for username try and use: apikey

- password the provided apikey key

- apikey: apikey

- endpoint url: the provided URL in IBM Cloud (should be under APIkey)
```

2) use a "http request" node and use the information example provided for curl

E.g: 
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \

--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \

--data-binary @{path_to_file}audio-file.flac \

"{url}/v1/recognize"

Answer (score 0):

please check this [Git Hub starter kit](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/starter-kits/ok_watson), from my point of view it would a good start for a solution of your issue. You see the section with  comment "speech in" this would be a possible solution.